# Microstrategy: With a drop down box Year, how to show values of the selected Year and Previous year in a grid

Tags: sql, sql-server, microstrategy

With a drop down selector 'Year' attribute (All is disabled), how to target a grid report to show values of the selected Year and Previous year?

For example:

```
     User selects year '2012' from the drop down, 
     the grid should display values of metrics for year 2012 in one column 
     and 2011 in another column for comparison purpose. 
     Metric headers are rows and year attribute is column.
```

Please note, the dataset is created with freeform sql.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There just isn't anywhere near enough information here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using transformations in MicroStrategy. Please go through the link for more details.
[Link to MicroStrategy Community](https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/architect/article-id/1742)

However, As you have mentioned that you are using a free form SQL, In this case write another pass of SQL like below and join result of this pass with original pass of SQL using Year column.

Select Fact.Year, Sum(Fact.Metric)
From Fact JOIN  Lookup
on (Fact.Year = Lookup.Year - 1)
Group by Fact.Year